# Pandas Data Reader Tiingo Errors when pulling multiple symbols if one symbol does not exist or is delisted

Tags: python, pandas, stock, pandas-datareader, tiingo

I am writing an app to track stock data entered into a spreadsheet.
I currently have it working by making a call to `pandas_datareader.tiingo.TiingoDailyReader` for every symbol.
The data reader is capable of taking a list of symbols and pulling all the data for those symbols at once.
I prefer this because I can make one call then query the dataframe it returns.

The issue I'm running into is when a symbol is delisted or does not exist this causes the entire call to fail resulting in an empty dataframe.
I've worked around this a little bit by checking all the symbols against a list of supported symbols for Tiingo.
However, this is not perfect as I have run into a instances where a symbol is supported but does not have data for the dates I request.

Is there a way to call all the symbols at once and have the data reader skip these errors or return no data for the problem symbol?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the symbols and start and end dates before you run the data acquisition. The reference is from the [official reference](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readers/tiingo.html)

```
import urllib.request
import pandas as pd
import io

url = 'https://apimedia.tiingo.com/docs/tiingo/daily/supported_tickers.zip'
zip_tickers = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
zip_tick = io.BytesIO(zip_tickers)

with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_tick) as myzip:
    csv_data = myzip.extract('supported_tickers.csv')  

df = pd.read_csv(csv_data, sep=',')

df
    ticker  exchange    assetType   priceCurrency   startDate   endDate
0   000001  SHE Stock   CNY 2007-08-30  2020-09-11
1   000002  SHE Stock   CNY 2000-01-04  2020-09-11
2   000003  SHE Stock   CNY NaN NaN
3   000004  SHE Stock   CNY 2007-08-31  2020-09-11
4   000005  SHE Stock   CNY 2001-01-02  2020-09-11
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
87303   ZZK NYSE ARCA   Stock   USD 2020-07-22  2020-09-11
87304   ZZLL    OTCBB   Stock   USD 2017-09-26  2020-09-11
87305   ZZLLD   OTCBB   Stock   USD 2017-10-06  2017-10-30
87306   ZZZ NYSE ARCA   Stock   USD 2014-10-31  2020-09-11
87307   ZZZOF   PINK    Stock   USD 2017-09-22  2020-09-11
87308 rows × 6 columns
```